# Typescript two layer union type infer in generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I want to write a small language by TypeScript and I define the basic data type for it:

```js
type BasicDataType = {
    kind: 'text'
} | {
    kind: 'number'
};
```

Then I defined a generic type to express its instance:

```js
type BasicInstance<B extends BasicDataType> = B extends { kind: 'number' } ?
    number
    : B extends { kind: 'text' } ?
    string
    : never;

let a: BasicInstance<{ kind: 'number' }> = 1;
let b: BasicInstance<{ kind: 'text' }> = '';
```

It works well, but when I try to define a advanced type and its instance:

```js
type DataType = {
    kind: 'single',
    t: BasicDataType
} | {
    kind: 'array',
    t: BasicDataType,
};
type Instance<D extends DataType> = D extends { kind: 'single', t: infer B } ?
    BasicInstance<B>
    : D extends { kind: 'array', t: infer B } ?
    Array<BasicInstance<B>>
    : never;
```

I got the error:

> error TS2344: Type 'B' does not satisfy the constraint 'BasicDataType'.
> Type 'B' is not assignable to type '{ kind: "number"; }'.

It seems TypeScript cannot understand that B must be a BasicDataType. Why it happen? And How do I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you just use BasicDataType instead of B? https://tsplay.dev/Nd34Yw

Comment: I think B is one kind of BasicDataType (maybe {kind: 'text'} or {kind: 'number'}}), it depends on what D is.

Comment: For both cases in DataType, t will just be BasicDataType. The type engine cannot know whether it's `{ kind: 'text' }` or `{ kind: 'number' }`. The only thing it could be derive is B = BasicDataType.

Comment: OK, but the error message seems typescript could not derive B = BasicDataType?

Comment: That's indeed the error. I believe this is just a limitation of TypeScript, in that it doesn't take into account any constraints on the inferred types, but I haven't found a clear description of it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inferred types are not always as exact as you would expect. Take this type definition for example:

```
type NotWorking<T extends {x: {y: number}}> =
  T extends {x: infer N} ? N['y'] : never
```

It fails with a `Type '"y"' cannot be used to index type 'N'.`, even though because of the `T extends {x: {y: number}}` constraint, `N['y']` should exist. To make it type check, you can add another condition `N extends {y: number}`, which will always pass:

```
type Working<T extends {x: {y: number}}> =
  T extends {x: infer N} ? N extends {y: number} ? N['y'] : never : never
```

For your type you could put an `B extends BasicDataType` extra condition on the outside and use `infer K` for the kind so you only need one `extends` condition to cover all kinds:

```
type Instance<D extends DataType> =
  D extends { kind: infer K, t: infer B }
  ? B extends BasicDataType
    ? K extends 'single' ? BasicInstance<B> 
    : K extends 'array' ? Array<BasicInstance<B>>
    : never
   : never
: never
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwJYGMAidhwCrmgXigG8AoKcqAayQDsATALigHJgIAPYZkgXygB9iZCtXpNmNAK4BbAEYQATtx4BuEiVCRYiVAEkaCLDRQQAPDCgc29BNuTpMOPAD4ohC1Yg3iVWoxZScorMUHwA-MLkgfIKkVBMHpxedLZEvmIsbJwh4XGGCrQA5nFMNBAAbopqJAA2EMBQcAk6KPqGcMZmaaL%20EjIxOa6EAIxqdQ2yzfZtRiam3X7iWVyhQyzM1ZrQGFi4WoSkFOm9yDSFdcwANHHAU6g7TpC8AkJHPeJwCgpwIFc3dw5dnhrqp1AB6MFQLZQGYdOZoSxJbwPPYQNYIzzeBYZZinc4QK5Qpi0ABmilgoSgEQhRzsegMszMMGcJBpRyYGKRKR87xYn2%20v0uRKgpPJFlybIoAEEvj9zC1YZ1zM4WZLyKUKlV1NDFfDEdZuSiXG5hJyDaljsSaGSFFAANJC24i61i0LCMIUzHc%20D2I1PI4eu365K2XFFC5UumtBlwpmuEr24PeZj8n4hD0%20%20ntJXMhNlSqxCgagskYuKbV4KAAOQA9sAAOo1hSiQqmbBJ7lEdhMIggUr9RQ8HhDYTtr2pbvOm3V8LVgDazF%20AF14lB8%20WNJXG82im2OxOe321wOFEOR%20Qx1yD1PyVXZ1X98Qj9FB5Gqwvl6v17ay7FN1psAgQw3CgbcW3mSde37IJT2HEggA)

Comment: This is a good answer.  I don’t like to sidestep the actual questions that people are asking, but I will say that in this example a union type makes more sense than a conditional.

Comment: Fair point :-) I tend to try and answer the question as asked though as often it will be a stripped down version of the actual problem anyway.

Comment: I'm reading the question again and I kind of missed the "two layer" part at first so it's not as straightforward of a case for union types as I was thinking it was anyways.